# how to modify multiples BoxCollider on a same game object?

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript, collider

I have an game object with multiples BoxCollider attached to it, is there a way to get all the BoxCollider to an array so that I could modify their value individually ?

Answer (score 1):

[`GetComponents()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html) will do what you need.

Comment: Or GetComponentsInChildren if any of them are in child objects.

Answer (score 1):

I made the `BoxColliderArray` public just so you can see it in the inspector.

```
    public BoxCollider[] BoxColliderArray;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        BoxColliderArray = GetComponents<BoxCollider>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //TODO: Do something with the BoxColliderArray

    }
```

[image]